# Acrobat JavaScript form field check/uncheck

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, adobe

i have problem with PDF fillable form.

I have three checkboxes (A, B and C) with same name and different value for "radio button" functions. (this mean only one checkbox can be checked).

Next, I duplicate this three fields to another page on PDF Form, beceause it is 2 copies of form in one PDF document).

I need another checkbox called "Discount" (also twice in document), but it can be checked only if "C" checkbox is checked.

In cosequence, when "C" checkbox is checked and "Discount" is checked" and user change main checkbox to "B" or "A", discound checkbox must be automaticaly deselected.

Can you help me ? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tired so far?

Comment: i tried this solution: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/797188

Comment: but i have field with name, export value, and "on/off" status - i dont know to get value of "on/off" status.

Comment: On/Off are the export values... just compare the value to "On" and you'll know if it is checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent access to the Discount box, make it visible only when the first checkbox group's C is checked. Otherwise, hide it and set it to "Off".

In a general calculation script (which is considered best practice), you would add the following code snippet (assuming the ABC checkbox field name is abc.ckb).

```
if (this.getField("abc.ckb").value != "C") {
this.getField("Discount").display = display.hidden ;
this.getField("Discount").value = "Off" ;
} else {
this.getField("Discount").display = display.visible 
}
```

… and that should do it.

Note that the field value for "unchecked" is always `"Off"` .